# What does the command cd . mean?

Tags: linux

I understand that cd .. goes up a directory, but what exactly does **cd .** do?

This is a question on my study guide, which is why I am asking.

Thanks!

Comment: It won't do anything! BTW, did you try on your own?

Comment: I did try and I got that it did nothing, but I wanted to confirm that it wasn't doing something behind the scenes that I was unaware of.

Answer (score 2):

As most people realize, `cd .` doesn't really do anything, because `.` means "the current directory". Changing to the current directory is seemingly pointless.

**However**, there is at least one interesting side effect:

When you `cd` to some directory, an environment variable `OLDPWD` is set, which allows you to execute `cd -` to return to the previous directory that you `cd`'ed from. When you execute `cd .`, `OLDPWD` actually gets set as the current directory, so it renders `cd -` ineffective in getting you back to the previous directory you were in.

Example:

```
$ cd /foo
$ cd /tmp
$ cd -
$ pwd
/foo
```

I'm in `/foo` just like I expected, **but**

```
$ cd /foo
$ cd /tmp
$ cd . # does nothing, right?
$ cd -
$ pwd
/tmp
```

Now I didn't return to `/foo` like I was hoping, due to this side effect!

Comment: **And** it adds "cd ." to your history! Wow! :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. **cd** changes directory to the argument provided. And **.** means "the current directory" just as **..** means "the parent of the current directory".

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `cd .` will change to the current directory, which has basically no effect in scripting/programming or to the operating system.

However that doesn't mean it will do *nothing*. In practice, you may be using a terminal to type this command. It will happily execute the command and - perhaps, though not likely - do something like echo the contents of the directory. If something else on your system (say a background process or another shell) have changed the contents of the directory, you may see modified output when the command echoes out the new directory listing.

In short: the `cd .` command doesn't have any real effect, but it could - in rare instances - have useful *side effects* that you could leverage in practical use.